# How to query model with association in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a UserEvent class for my event management app, and a user event can have many event dates for when the events occur:

```
class UserEvent < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :event_dates
  ...
end
```

The EventDate class has a user_event_date property:

```
class EventDate < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_event_date, :start_time, :end_time
  belongs_to :user_event, inverse_of: :event_dates
  ...
end
```

I have a Search class, and when a search is executed, the find_user_events method filters the user events, so only user events remain whose user_event_date is between the search object user_event_date_from and user_event_date_to properties.

```
class Search < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_event_date_from, :user_event_date_to

  private 
    def find_user_events
      if user_event_date_from.present? || user_event_date_to.present?
        time_range = user_event_date_from..user_event_date_to
        user_events = UserEvent.joins(:event_dates).where(event_dates: {user_event_date: time_range}) 
    end
end
```

But the filter does not work, all records are returned. I got this "where" code from this Rails guide under the section "Specifying Conditions on the Joined Tables":

[Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables)

So my questions:

- how to get this to work?
- if user specifies only user_event_date_from (user_event_date_to  will be  nil) will this work, as the range will be from   user_event_date_from  to   nil, or should I detect that and set the range to:    user_event_date_from..user_event_date_from

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be too tricky to debug .. open your rails console and stick in

```
UserEvent.joins(:event_dates).where(event_dates: { user_event_date: 10.days.ago..DateTime.now })
```

..or change the dates so that you know you will get some data returned. Check the data is correct. If that works then your problem is elsewhere.

As for your other question, if you try and use `nil` in a range you'll get `ArgumentError: bad value for range`. So yes, depending on how you want it to behave, the usual solution is to check for nil values and replace it with something appropriate for the behaviour you'd like to implement.

**Edit** - Oddly, `nil..nil` as a range doesn't produce an ArgumentError, which could mean that you're not setting the values successfully. How are you setting the values of `user_event_date_from` and `user_event_date_to`?

Comment: They are passed in, I think implicitly, as part of the search. They should be there, as seen by this other part of the function's filtering mechanism, which accesses other search properties in a similar manner:       user_events = user_events.where(state_id: state_id) if state_id.present?
      user_events = user_events.where(postal_code: postal_code) if postal_code.present?

Comment: Dude again..How are you setting the values of user_event_date_from and user_event_date_to?

Comment: We can't debug your app for you because we don't have your app. Also, you didn't answer either of my suggestions for debugging. Work backwards from the values of `user_event_date_from` and `user_event_date_to` in your `find_user_events` method, and I'm sure you'll work it out.

Comment: Executing what you suggested in the console returned one record, no matter if the range is 10.days.ago, 30, or 50, and I know there should be more data. I'll poke around and we'll see. Thanks for the suggestions!